# How were the manuscripts of the Bible written?

Tags: greek, hebrew, hebrew-bible

Did they have spaces, punctuation, paragraphs...?

I mean the manuscripts that are closer to the original ones, do we know how the prophets wrote it?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) This is a rather broad question and is likely to be closed - please do also check out the [help centre](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you need more guidance on what's a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Title question doesn’t make clear which manuscripts you’re referring to – Masoretic texts, Septuagint ones, Koine Greek, original autographs, copies, translated ones, e.g. the Latin Vulgate? What do you mean when you say ‘written’? Do you mean what type of paper/parchment were they written on? Were they written in uncials or miniscules? Were they in scroll or codex form?

Anyway, your additional question identifies only punctuation, spaces and paragraphs … so in a nutshell, the experts tell us that the original Hebrew, the language of the Old Testament, the Koine Greek, the language of the Septuagint (the Old Testament translated into Greek) and the New Testament - generally speaking - didn’t have any kind of punctuation or spaces. The following information might provide a useful starting point for further study:

**Masoretic Hebrew**

Here’s a link to an interesting, 26 page, PDF file published by the British and Foreign Bible Society which gives an outline of how punctuation developed and evolved in Masoretic Hebrew texts:

http://lc.bfbs.org.uk/e107_files/downloads/masoretes.pdf

In general they state that ancient languages were not punctuated. In Aristotle’s day, the only known punctuation was a line to indicate when a new topic would follow. It indicated what we would call a new paragraph. Here’s a snippet from the PDF file:

> “The earliest Hebrew manuscripts, in common with many ancient languages, had no punctuation system (except for starting a new line to indicate a new topic) and Hebrew had no vowels in its alphabet. Neither of these omissions was important as long as Hebrew was a spoken language. Cases where a vowel could readily be mistaken were to some extent catered for at an early period by inserting consonants to help the reader: h for an a sound, y for e or i and w for u (although many ambiguities remained). Full stops were inserted to divide the text into sentences or verses, possibly as early as the second century BCE, and most verses were marked to indicate the most important pause to make when reading aloud. Before the Talmud was completed the rabbis had emended these for consistency and had added other marks to clarify the text. A vertical bar | was written between words when it was felt necessary to clarify where one ended and another began (inter-word spaces were not regularly used), and stress markers were inserted.” (Page 4)

From an Article titled: “The Masoretes and the Punctuation of Biblical Hebrew” Page 4. Available at: http://lc.bfbs.org.uk/e107_files/downloads/masoretes.pdf [Accessed 7th April 2016]

**Koine Greek**

All sources I come across state that the Greek language had no punctuation until the Second Century AD. If true, this means that when the apostles wrote the letters and books which were later compiled into the New Testament, they wrote without any spaces or punctuation. Koine Greek originally had an alphabet of only capital letters (uncials), without any spacing between words. Lower case letters (miniscules) were developed around the 9th Century.

According to Porter et al (2010), New Testament Greek punctuation wasn’t found in any consistent form before the 6th Century. Daniel Wallace (Greek New Testament Expert) points out that the absence of dictionaries meant there were various types of spellings for the same word – anything went, which is one reason why you get spelling variations in New Testament manuscripts (i.e. scribal copies of the original autographs). Perhaps the same could be true for punctuation? If there wasn’t a set rule, perhaps some copyists used punctuation, while the majority didn’t. Porter et al writes:

> “Edited texts of the Greek New Testament do not always agree on punctuation. In fact, the two major editions — the Nestle-Aland (27th ed.) and the UBSGNT (3rd and 4th eds.) — have essentially the same printed text but in some cases different punctuation.13 Punctuation is used to indicate whether certain clauses are questions or statements, or to indicate when major and minor breaks occur. It is an addition to the original text **not found consistently or in quantity before the sixth century a.d.** Hence there is room for editors to disagree on punctuation, although in some instances grammar can help make this decision. The four punctuation marks are period (.), which indicates a complete break between sentences, as it does in English; comma (,), which indicates a minor break between phrases or clauses, also as in English; raised dot, or colon (·), which indicates an intermediate-level break, somewhat equivalent to the English semicolon or colon; and question mark (;), which looks like an English semicolon.” (Page 14) Emphasis added.

From an Article titled “Fundamentals of New Testament Greek”. Available from: http://www.portergreek.com/pdfs/portergreek_chapter1.pdf [Accessed 7th April 2016]

The Wikipedia page on Koine Greek shows an image of Papyrus 46, one of the oldest New Testament manuscripts we have. If you enlarge it, you’ll see that there are no spaces or punctuation markers. The image can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek

Here’s a link for further study you might find interesting:

http://www.friktech.com/rel/canon/types.htm

And here’s a link to a Blog by a Greek Language Expert where people comment on this very subject:

http://greek-language.com/grklinguist/?p=657

One contributor says there’s evidence of punctuation and spacing in one Greek Bible manuscript, Greek Papyrus 457 located at Manchester University Library, viewable here:

http://enriqueta.man.ac.uk/luna/servlet/detail/ManchesterDev~93~3~22986~100256?trs=4&qvq=q%3Agreek+papyrus+457%3Blc%3Aman~3~3%2Cmaps2~1~1%2CManchester~91~1%2CManchesterDev~95~2%2CLearning_and_Research~91~1%2CMan4MedievalVC~4~4%2Cnonconform~91~1%2CManchesterDev~93~3%2Clib1~1~1&mi=0

However, according to Porter et al above, punctuated Greek NT texts weren’t consistent nor found in quantity prior to the 6th Century.

P.S. I can’t vouch for the credibility of any of these web links!

**CONCLUSION**

Hebrew experts tell us that the original Old Testament autographs and early copies of those autographs did not have spaces or punctuation apart from starting a new line to indicate a new topic, similar to our paragraph. (I haven't done a thorough study of this, so there might be exceptions.)

Greek experts tell us that the Septuagint (Old Testament translated into Greek) and the original autographs of the New Testament did not have spaces or punctuation. The Greek New Testament manuscript copies **generally speaking** did not have spaces or punctuation. There are a small number of NT manuscript copies which did have spaces and evidence of punctuation, but these were the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Hi Marisa, thank you for putting this together. Unfortunately the question has now been closed as "too broad" (there were also some votes for "unclear what you're asking"). Your introductory paragraph indicates that you recognized this problem with the question as well. Just so you know for next time: when a question leaves you with that many uncertainties about the OP's interests, it's best to request clarification in a comment or, once you have enough rep to do so, vote to close **rather than** answering.

Comment: P.S. I am unaware of any ancient Hebrew manuscripts without spacing. Because most medial vowels were not indicated in writing prior to ~10th C., there is substantial ambiguity already in the Hebrew of (e.g.) the Dead Sea Scrolls; lack of word divisions seems like it might render them too ambiguous to be intelligible. DSS that I've looked at all have spaces. Earlier mss generally had even more ambiguity (due to orthographic shifts), so I can't imagine them without spaces, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I believe your answer suffices my expectations and answers my question, thank you. Much love, blessings.

Comment: @susan Thanks for those additional thoughts. If a question is 'closed' does that mean that the question and answer will  be removed? It will be a shame if they are because the person who asked '144ky' commented above to say the answer answered her question. If the question and answer was allowed to stay, it could perhaps be a useful spring board for further study for others asking similar questions? :-)

Comment: @144Ky much love and blessings to you too! :-)